# Breakpoint in a particular case

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, gdb, g++

Recently I coded up a function that wasn't working properly. I managed to find out what was wrong and fix it in a roundabout manner but I was wondering if there was an easier way. The function (stripped down) is something like this:

```
int func(int param)
{
  if(param == 0) return SOMETHING;
  //...
  for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
    // Point A
    func(param - 1);
  }
  //...
}
```

I wanted to set a breakpoint at Point A so I could see what happens for param = 10 (for example) and i = 0, 1, 2, 3 but the problem is, the function is recursive so it calls itself with (in this case) param = 9, 8,... I was wondering if there was a way to set the breakpoint for only a certain case. I used MS Visual C++ Express 2008 in this case but if there's a way to do it with another compiler (g++/gdb perhaps) then that would be helpful too.

Comment: The easy solution: `if (param == 10) DebugBreak();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can right-click the breakpoint and modify it in all kinds of ways.
Under `Condition...` you can specifiy your condition, like `param == 10`. You can even use simple C library functions for string comparision `strcmp(mystr,"hi") == 0`!

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio debugger supports conditional breakpoints.  After you put a breakpoint in the editor, right click it and select "Condition..."

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can set [conditional breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx) (not sure about other environments). If you want to do this in any C++ environment `ASSERT` is always an option.

```
ASSERT(param != 10);
```

Comment: `ASSERT` is certainly *not* an option if you want to continue after breaking.

Comment: @xeo - why not? Continuing after an assert (and attaching a debugger if not present) works just fine (at least in an MS dev environment perhaps I made an incorrect assumption about how it works elsewhere)

Comment: Really? I use VS2010 and `assert` calls `abort`, which can't be recovered from (or at least I don't know how).